# HTML Select Multiple - Find which option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several SELECT tags with some options.

Selected options must be unique in all lists, while unselected options are shared and should be available for each select.

Then, when some option is selected in one SELECT, it should be removed from other lists. When some option is unselected, then it should be available again in all lists.

My problem is that I can't find which option is just (un)selected. I tried onChange event on SELECT but can't find which option is selected last. Also, I tried various events on OPTION tag but event is not triggered.

Of course, if I use value of SELECT in JavaScript then I just get all values separated by comma and I can't know from that which value is just added or removed.

Is it possible to use some event on OPTION tag, to get value of currently selected or unselected item?

Thanks!

Comment: Keep track of the selections, when change is fired, compare to the last know set. The one that is not in the set was un-selected.

Comment: Share your code also !

Comment: @epascarello I got that idea and hoped that I could avoid it lol. Nishant, not much of code, I just try to find out which option is selected or unselected in select when multiple is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach will update all selects so that once an item is selected it is removed from counterparts. Conversely deselecting will also add the option back to others

```
var $selects = $('select'),
    $storedOpts = $selects.first().children().clone();

$selects.change(function(){        
    $selects.not(this).each(function(){
        var otherVals = $.map($selects.not(this).find(':selected'),function(opt){
           return opt.value
       });
        var currVal = $(this).val();
        var $options = $storedOpts.clone().filter(function(_, option){
            return $.inArray(option.value, otherVals) == -1;
        })
        $(this).html($options).val(currVal);

    });  

});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zu7txyec/1)**</kbd>

Comment: Wow! @charlietfl thanks so much, it works perfectly. Ingenious code! Wonder why this problem got 4 down votes? Weird people...

Comment: @BorisP to be honest when you post questions that don't show code attempts they do get downvotes. *Give a man a fish...or teach a man to fish...*

Comment: got it now. I hoped to just get info about how to get reference to changed option, so my code would eventually be just plain <select multiple> with two <option> tags inside :). Certainly didn't expect complete solution like the one you provided. Thank you again! So simple and fast. I tried something with iteration through each node and comparing arrays, but this is far better. And I certainly did learn something regarding to fishing of jQuery. :)

Comment: I do enjoy creating little snippets like this though. They are good exercises

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all options in the select element, and determine if each one is selected like this:

```
var selectele = document.getElementById('your_select_id');
for(var i = 0; i < selectele.options.length; i++){
    var option = selectele.options[i];
    if(option.selected){
        // this option is selected
    }else{
        // this option is not selected
    }
}
```

Using this, you can keep a separate list of all available options in your javascript code, and rebuild the entire options lists any time anything changes. Then you don't have to account for every way any of the select lists could possibly change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.data()` in jQuery to store the previously selected value for use later, and then just bind to the change event:

**Example:**

```js
$('.foo').change(function() {

  // setup
  var option = $(this).find(':selected'),
    text = option.text(),
    self = $(this),
    data = $(this).data('prev'),
    foos = $('.foo');

  // unhide
  if (text === '-- select --') {
    foos.not(self).each(function() {
      var unhide = $(this).children('option').filter(function() {
        return $(this).html() == data; // <-- previous
      });
      unhide.show();
    });
  } else { // hide
    foos.not(self).each(function() {
      var hide = $(this).children('option').filter(function() {
        return $(this).html() == text; // <-- current
      });
      hide.hide();
    });
  }

  // store the previously selected value  
  $(this).data('prev', text);

});
```

```css
.foo {
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="foo">
  <option>-- select --</option>
  <option>bar</option>
  <option>bim</option>
  <option>baz</option>
</select>
<select class="foo">
  <option>-- select --</option>
  <option>bar</option>
  <option>bim</option>
  <option>baz</option>
</select>
<select class="foo">
  <option>-- select --</option>
  <option>bar</option>
  <option>bim</option>
  <option>baz</option>
</select>
```

Comment: unfortunately some browsers don't support hiding `<option>`...IE & Safarai for example

Comment: It's a pretty trivial difference to delete / add vs hide / show.

Comment: not really trivial vs hide/show ... requires more logic to be able to add